# Set multiple cursor with Ace Editor

Tags: cursor, editor, ace-editor

I tried to set multiple cursors on Ace Editor, I know this question is already asked, but the answer is old and it seems to not work anymore.

So, I've read the perfect example for setting multiple cursors in this file:
https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/lib/ace/search_highlight.js

But when I watch this code, I don't understand how to use the SearchHighlight Object? I've searched in the others files but I've not found.